# Objective-C: JWT - Encode with RS256 using string data of a private key

Tags: ios, objective-c, jwt

I'm using this library to encode a `RS256` token https://github.com/yourkarma/JWT

In the docs there is an example that deals with `RS256` encoding

```
NSDictionary *payload = @{@"payload" : @"hidden_information"};
NSString *algorithmName = @"RS256";

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"secret_key" ofType:@"p12"];
NSData *privateKeySecretData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSString *passphraseForPrivateKey = @"secret";

JWTBuilder *builder = [JWTBuilder encodePayload:payload].secretData(privateKeySecretData).privateKeyCertificatePassphrase(passphraseForPrivateKey).algorithmName(algorithmName);
NSString *token = builder.encode;
```

Now, since I only have a string of a private key similar like this:

```
"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAtN7LQq7l9a9....SUug==\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

I'm wondering how I can implement that? Obviously I don't need a passphrase.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it wasn't that hard, with a help of a workmate ;-)

Here's the solution:

```
NSDictionary *payload = @{@"payload" : @"hidden_information"};

id <JWTAlgorithmDataHolderProtocol> holder = [JWTAlgorithmRSFamilyDataHolder new]
    .keyExtractorType([JWTCryptoKeyExtractor privateKeyWithPEMBase64].type)
    .privateKeyCertificatePassphrase(nil)
    .algorithmName(JWTAlgorithmNameRS256)
    .secret(<string of the private key as above>);

JWTCodingResultType *result = [JWTEncodingBuilder encodePayload:payload]
    .addHolder(holder)
    .result;

NSString *token = result.successResult.encoded;
NSError *error = result.errorResult.error;
```